# Validation and ajax one of these not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

After the validation code, I wrote some ajax code, but when I write the onclick="return chk()" in field input submit, then the validation code doesn't work anymore, and when I delete it the validation code is working but the ajax doesn't, so what can the issue be ?????????????

ajax and jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

 $.validator.addMethod("alphabet", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
    });
  $("#registration").validate({

    rules: {

      name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength : 3,
                    alphabet: true,
      },  

      vorname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength : 3,
                    alphabet: true,


      },  

      email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
      },

       url: {
                    url: true,
      },

       image:{
                    required:true,
                    accept:"png",
                }
    },
    messages: {

                     name:{
                        required:"Name ist benötigen",
                        minlength :"Name muss mendisten 3 Buchstaben",

                    },

                    vorname:{
                        required:" Vorname ist benötigen",
                        minlength :"Name muss mendisten 3 Buchstaben",

                    },
                    email:{
                       required :" Email ist benötigen",
                       email :" Email muss"
                    },
                    Url:" URL muss benötigen",
                    image:"Image muss nur PNG sein",



    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
      alert ('Vielen Danke Für Ihre Anmeldung');
    }
  });
});

function chk(){

                        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                        var vorname = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
                        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
                        var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
                        var image = document.getElementById('image').value;

                        var dataString='name='+ name + '&vorname='+vorname+ '&email='+email+ '&url='+url+ '&image='+image;
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"post",
                            url:"mainphp.php",
                            data:dataString,
                            cashe:false,
                            success:function(info){
                                $('#msg').html(info);
                            }

                        })
                        return false; 
                    }
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"" ></script> 
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
                <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>          
        <form class="form" name="registration" id="registration" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
            <br><br>
            <label for="vorname">Vorame</label>
            <input type="text" name="vorname" id="vorname" value="">
            <br><br>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email"  id="email" value="">
            <br><br>
            <label for="name">URL</label>
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="">
            <br><br>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" >
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return chk()" >
        </form>
            <p id="msg"></p>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use either jquery.js or jquery.min.js and please provide the full path of your js files so that we can debug the code.

Comment: @AlokMali i wrote  the full path now

Comment: why don't you remove `form.submit` and directly call `chk()` function there.

Comment: @Jeeva not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the chk() function directly like below

```
$.validator.addMethod("alphabet", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
    });
  $("#registration").validate({

    rules: {

      name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength : 3,
                    alphabet: true,
      },  

      vorname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength : 3,
                    alphabet: true,


      },  

      email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
      },

       url: {
                    url: true,
      },

       image:{
                    required:true,
                    accept:"png",
                }
    },
    messages: {

                     name:{
                        required:"Name ist benötigen",
                        minlength :"Name muss mendisten 3 Buchstaben",

                    },

                    vorname:{
                        required:" Vorname ist benötigen",
                        minlength :"Name muss mendisten 3 Buchstaben",

                    },
                    email:{
                       required :" Email ist benötigen",
                       email :" Email muss"
                    },
                    Url:" URL muss benötigen",
                    image:"Image muss nur PNG sein",



    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      formData = new FormData(form);
      chk(form);
      return false;
      alert ('Vielen Danke Für Ihre Anmeldung');
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: i add the function chk() inside the $(document).ready(function()  and i wrote what you wrote in submitHandler and it's work the Konsole give me warning "unreachable code after return statement" but it's working thx

Comment: remove alert. That error should go. If solved please accept this as answer.

Comment: i switch the alert with return and it's working thank you i already did

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call a function on onClick to send data at the server, You can put your code in submitHandler. The advantage of it is that if the form is invalid it will don't send any request (post data) to the server.

```
  <!DOCTYPE >
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
        <script
          language="javascript"
          type="text/javascript"
          src="javascript.js"
        ></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form
          class="form"
          name="registration"
          id="registration"
          action=""
          method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
        >
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
          <br /><br />
          <label for="vorname">Vorame</label>
          <input type="text" name="vorname" id="vorname" value="" />
          <br /><br />
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
          <br /><br />
          <label for="name">URL</label>
          <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="" />
          <br /><br />
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
          <br /><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <p id="msg"></p>
      </body>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
          $.validator.addMethod("alphabet", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
          });
          $("#registration").validate({
            rules: {
              name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                alphabet: true
              },

              vorname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                alphabet: true
              },

              email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
              },

              url: {
                url: true
              },

              image: {
                required: true,
                accept: "png"
              }
            },
            messages: {
              name: {
                required: "Name ist benötigen",
                minlength: "Name muss mendisten 3 Buchstaben"
              },

              vorname: {
                required: " Vorname ist benötigen",
                minlength: "Name muss mendisten 3 Buchstaben"
              },
              email: {
                required: " Email ist benötigen",
                email: " Email muss"
              },
              Url: " URL muss benötigen",
              image: "Image muss nur PNG sein"
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
              var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
              var vorname = document.getElementById("vorname").value;
              var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
              var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
              var image = document.getElementById("image").value;

              var dataString =
                "name=" +
                name +
                "&vorname=" +
                vorname +
                "&email=" +
                email +
                "&url=" +
                url +
                "&image=" +
                image;
              $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "mainphp.php",
                data: dataString,
                cashe: false,
                success: function(info) {
                  $("#msg").html(info);
                }
              });
              //alert("Vielen Danke Für Ihre Anmeldung");
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </html>
```